# Always center bar on ordinal for bar charts

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, bar-chart, rect

Let's say you have a d3.js scale as so (we're assuming horizontal bar chart here)

```
var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .rangeRoundBands([0,height]); //height of chart
```

A common way to then create bars is to append rects to your svg. Below is some common sample code. I've excluded various other attributes in order to just focus on `y` and `height`:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d) { return yScale(d); })
  .attr("height", yScale.rangeBand());
```

However, for graphs of just 2-3 elements, it causes each band to be very large. I want to enable a 'maxBarHeight' stipulation, but I'm having trouble ensuring that the bar is always centered on the ordinal. This is what I have so far:

```
svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data)
.enter().append("rect")
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    if(yScale.rangeBand() > maxBarHeight)
      return yScale(d) + (maxBarHeight / 2); //This doesn't work
    else
      return yScale(d);
  })
  .attr("height", (yScale.rangeBand() > maxBarHeight ? maxBarHeight : yScale.rangeBand()))
```

Is there a simpler way to control bar size while maintaining alignment?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Do you want to modify the height of the bars depending on the number of bars?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Essentially yes, and I would like them to always be centered around the values returned by `yScale(d)`. A bonus would be to establish a maximum height value, so if a chart only has two bars, I don't want them to be huge.

Comment: That doesn't sound like a bar chart at all. Could you make a mock-up picture to give us a better idea of what you're looking for?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Just to be clear, I'm talking about a horizontal bar chart here, not a vertical chart, so talk of "bar height" can be thought of as "bar width".

Comment: Ah ok, that makes more sense. So you have the height thing already, right? Still not sure what you mean with the centering though -- do you want the x axis in the middle of the bars?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Since it's a horizontal chart, the y-axis is an ordinal scale. I want my bars to be centered around the ordinal (aka the value returned by `yScale(d)`). Something similar to way you can do `.style("text-anchor", "middle")` or `align=middle`'. It seems like default behavior is to have the top edge of the bar start at the ordinal, and expand downward.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "centred around the value `yScale(d)`" -- this is different for each bar, no? There's no single value to be centred around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the best way to control bar size and centering is to not mess around with the x/y or width/height attributes of the `rect`, but to instead use the padding parameters in `rangeBands()` or `rangeRoundBands()`. Below are some example charts plotting gender data:

#### Horizontal Chart (2 bars), default ordinal

`var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0,chartHeight]);`
[image: default_ordinal]

#### Horizontal Chart (2 bars), ordinal with inner padding

`var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0,chartHeight],.7);`
[image: inner_padding]

#### Horizontal Chart (2 bars), ordinal with inner & outer padding

`var yScale = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0,chartHeight],.5,.1);`
[image]

This method will let you adjust the bar size while maintaining alignment with the ordinal.